# Get azure service principal inside Azure ADO pipeline task and then pass it through to the next step in the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, service-principal

I have already created a service connection between existing subscription and ADO.

Problem statement 1:
I am running a simple ADO job which has just one Azure cli step. In the step I have checked the option to "Access service principal details in script". The inline script has just one statement
echo $servicePrincipalId
This works fine when I run in an ubuntu Agent but fails when I run using vs2017-win2016 server. Since we need to use windows agent could someone advice how to get this working?

Problem statement 2:
Once I get the service principal ie $servicePrincipalId I need to set this as an environmental variable so as to use this in my application (next step in pipeline) which reads of environmental variables.
Please could someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: For the first problem, what do you mean by " fails when I run using vs2017-win2016 server.", do you receive any error message in the log? The `scriptType` might affect, please "Select bash/pscore script when running on Linux agent or batch/ps/pscore script when running on Windows agent.", for this you can refer to the doc [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops#task-inputs). If it's `powershell`, you might need to use `Write-Output` instead.

Comment: For the second, you can use powershell script to set a variable with the `task.setvariable`. For example,`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=variablename isOutput=true]$servicePrincipalld"`. For more information about passing varible accrossing tasks, please check [How to use output variable from a Powershell "Script"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/676342/how-to-use-output-variable-from-a-powershell-scrip.html). Or if you just want to set it as environment variable, use `Write-Host '$Env:variablename = "variablevalue"'`.

Comment: @yang many thanks. Sorry what I meant by failing was I was unable to print the  $servicePrincipalld even by using the power shell syntax of Write-output. It just displays a blank when compared to running in Ubuntu which displays *** as I think it’s hiding the actual value which is fine.

Comment: Blank without error message, is it possible it's there but unable to see for security issue? Have you tried to set varible with it? I found [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8726), maybe it's similar to the situaition that you all want to use the `$servicePrincipalld`.

Comment: I have managed to get to a point where I am sure azure cli executes my commands properly, But to have this executed as an ADo pipeline task I think may not be possible as I would need to az login  with my username and password. The scripts I am using is
Install-Module -Name AzureAD -Force 
$ServicePrincipalId = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Top 1).ObjectId
Write-Host "Set environment variable to ($ServicePrincipalId)"
But the last line wont execute as I am not logged in.

Comment: The commands work well in azure cli but not in azure devops's azure cli task because you can not do az login in the task? According to [this azure cli task example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops#example), once the task the runs, you are already logged in, i mean it runs `az account show` directly without `az login`.